# How to center links in a collapsing bootstrap navigationbar with a searchbar on the right?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tumblr

I'm trying to customize my tumblr theme these days and I wanted to have a navigation bar that has icons in the middle and a search bar on the right and when the screen gets smaller the items of the navigation bar should appear in a dropdown menu. So far I have seen examples with buttons in the middle, on the left and right or just left and right. But I can't find the navigation bar I want. So I tried to adjust some samples but I get problems aligning the buttons to the middle. Either they don't want to get aligned to the middle or they are middled but get pushed to the left because of the search bar. Can someone help me out?

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');
 .navbar-nav {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.navbar-nav > li {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
.col-md-offset-4 {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">

  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>

  </div>

  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="row aligned-row">

    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-sm-offset-4 col-md-offset-4">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
      <form class="navbar-form pull-right" role="search">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="q">
          <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example, [here's how](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). **What have you tried (specifically)!? Where is your code!?**

Comment: Here's an example, as you can see the link group is not centered: http://codepen.io/didi-kong/pen/GryPKV

Comment: Please include your code in your post, not a link to the code.

Comment: Ok, added it in the post =)